# How to identify where the below azure transactions are coming from? How to estimate the cost associated with it?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-monitoring, azure-billing-api

We have a azure blob storage container which is NFS mounted on linux Virtual Machines. This container has blobs in Hot tier, Cool tier and Archive tier.

I see a lot of transactions (per day) in Azure Metrics for this storage account. We only have one container in the storage account.

Can you please help me narrow down from where these transactions are coming? And also may I know which category (Read, Iterative Read, All other operations) I should consider these transactions as in the Blob transactions pricing table?
**API NFS3LookUp Screenshot**

[image: API NFS3LookUp Screenshot]

**API NFS3GetAttr Screenshot**

[image: API NFS3GetAttr Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

For your transaction issue make use of [Azure Storage Analytics metrics (classic) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-metrics#billing-on-storage-metrics),This issues mainly because of many Duplicate records may exist for logs created in the same hour

***Make sure you enable Azure Storage Analytics metrics, in your storage account use blob container `$logs` which you can proceed to more log entries and find information*** and `$logs` are not worked when List Containers operation is accomplished.

For example :

`http://<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/$logs`.

You can try the below PowerShell cmdlet to filter the list of log blobs at specify time which you can done in your storage account container

```php
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container '$logs' |  
Where-Object {  
    $_.Name -match 'blob/2014/05/21/05' -and   
    $_.ICloudBlob.Metadata.LogType -match 'write'  
} |  
ForEach-Object {  
    "{0}  {1}  {2}  {3}" –f $_.Name,   
    $_.ICloudBlob.Metadata.StartTime,   
    $_.ICloudBlob.Metadata.EndTime,   
    $_.ICloudBlob.Metadata.LogType  
}
```

Otherwise, You can make use of [azure application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview) it can automatically detect performance and resolve your diagnose issues io understand what actually required

For your information please **refer** below link which answered by **sVathis** & **Gaurav Mantri** :

[How can I find the source of my Hot LRS Write Operations on Azure Storage Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55808709/how-can-i-find-the-source-of-my-hot-lrs-write-operations-on-azure-storage-accoun)

[Azure Storage Analytics logging | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging)

> And also may I know which category (Read, Iterative Read, All other operations) I should consider these transactions as in the Blob transactions pricing table

You can use [azure Pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?WT.mc_id=ITOpsTalk-blog-socuff) Pricing is depends on the region where the data is stored

[image]

please refer this [offical documents](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/storage/blobs/) for operations based on your requirement