# How to get request details coming to azure storage for monitoring?

Tags: azure, containers, azure-blob-storage

From the past few days, I am being charged for the LRS read and write operation in azure container storage. I have checked all the metrics of API calling to that azure container, but all are working normally. But in storage container metrics its showing lots of request every minute

[image]

So here request is around 35k in last few days. But I don't know from where all this request are coming.

Answer (score 0):

To get request details coming to Azure Storage for monitoring, you can make use of [**Storage Analytics**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics)

> **Azure Storage Analytics** performs logging and provides *metrics data for a storage account*. You can use this data to **trace requests**, analyze usage trends, and diagnose issues with your storage account.

Please check whether you have enabled Azure Storage Analytics metrics, if not enable like below:

***Go to Azure portal -> Storage Accounts -> Your storage account -> Monitoring -> Diagnostic settings***

[image]

**The diagnostic logs will be saved in container called **`$logs` which will appear after enabling [**Storage Analytics Logging**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging)****

[image]

*Please check whether you have any **Azure App services** or **Azure functions** that is using storage in background by enabling their Diagnostic settings.*

If the issue still persists, please raise [**Azure support request**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/) to know where exactly it is going wrong.

**References:**

[How can I find the source of my Hot LRS Write Operations on Azure Storage Account? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55808709/how-can-i-find-the-source-of-my-hot-lrs-write-operations-on-azure-storage-accoun)

[Azure Storage Analytics metrics (classic) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-metrics#billing-on-storage-metrics)